# Three.JS Blank Page without any Error in CSS3DRenderer

Tags: javascript, html, css, three.js

When I use CSS3DRenderer in my Code I get a blank page without any Error and I just want to get the Line using the CSS3DRenderer as my rest of code works with that only

HTML Code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" >
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>threejs line draw</title>
  <style>
  body { margin: 0; }
    canvas { width: 100%; height: calc(100% -10px) }
  </style>

</head>
<body>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/108/three.min.js'></script>
<script src="./lib/Tween.min.js"></script>
<script src="./lib/controls/TrackballControls.js"></script>
<script src="./lib/renderers/CSS3DRenderer.js"></script>
<script src="./script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

script.js

```
var renderer = new THREE.CSS3DRenderer();
renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 45, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 500 );
camera.position.set( 0, 0, 100 );
camera.lookAt( 0, 0, 0 );

var scene = new THREE.Scene();

var material = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial( { color: 0x0000ff } );

var geometry = new THREE.Geometry();
geometry.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3( -10, 0, 0) );
geometry.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3( -6, 6, 0) );
geometry.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3( 0, 10, 0) );
geometry.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3( 6, 6, 0) );
geometry.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3( 10, 0, 0) );

var line = new THREE.Line( geometry, material );

scene.add( line );
renderer.render( scene, camera );
```

Answer (score 1):

[CSS3DRenderer](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#examples/en/renderers/CSS3DRenderer) is only able to render instances of type `CSS3DObject` and `CSS3DSprite`. Both classes expect a HTML DOM element as their actual render item.

Meaning you can't render 3D objects holding geometries and materials (like `Mesh`, `Line` or `Points`) with `CSS3DRenderer`.